# Uniform Grid control with multiple Items C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, uniformgrid

I need a window like below ;

[image]

I tried to achieve this, but couldn't get 100% outcome. Where did I do wrong?

```
    <UniformGrid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Border  BorderBrush="Black" Background="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="3" Margin="2" Width="100" >  
              <Grid FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Label1Text}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2"/>

                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Label2Text}" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2"/>

                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Button1" Width="80" Height="80"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.Command1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Grid.Row="0"  Margin="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

   </ItemsControl>
  </UniformGrid>
```

Result window;

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change `ItemsPanel` template to `UniformGrid` instead of wrapping the `ItemsControl` within `UniformGrid`. You can also try using `WrapPanel` instead of `UniformGrid` :

```
.......
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2"/>
                <!--  <WrapPanel/> -->
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
.......
```

Comment: I didn't get you, do I have to change "<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>" to '<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>' ??

Comment: I meant, try to set `<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>` as above in addition to `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` you already have

Comment: WrapPanel doesn't allow you to set the number of columns

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the number of columns:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="2">
....
```